# plugin installation failed from own repo

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, repository

I have developed some plugins for use in our company only. And for the purpose of installing them and keeping them up to date, I created a repo and the users who need our plugins just add this repo to there qgis plugin managment.

The installation and the updates work fine for two of our plugins. But for the other two, the plugin installer seems to stop extracting files. It always happens and the files that are extracted are always the same. I tried rezipping them but it does nothing.

My repo-xml look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
   <pyqgis_plugin name="Dbg_Gruenkatastertoolbar" version="2.9.7">
     <description>d.b.g. Gruenkatastertoolbar - interaktive Schnittstelle zum d.b.g. Gruenflaechenkataster</description>
     <homepage>http://www.datenbankgesellschaft.de</homepage>
     <qgis_minimum_version>2.18</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>DbgGruen.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Jan Lippmann, Alexander Barth</author_name>
     <download_url>file:////dc1/dbg/software/produkte/gis/qgis-repo/dbggruen.zip</download_url>
   </pyqgis_plugin>
   <pyqgis_plugin name="Dbg_Strassenverwaltungstoolbar" version="1.2.0">
     <description>d.b.g. Strassenverwaltungstoolbar - interaktive Schnittstelle zur d.b.g. Strassenverwaltung</description>
     <homepage>http://www.datenbankgesellschaft.de</homepage>
     <qgis_minimum_version>2.18</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>DbgSaa.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Jan Lippmann, Alexander Barth</author_name>
     <download_url>file:////dc1/dbg/software/produkte/gis/qgis-repo/dbgsaa.zip</download_url>
   </pyqgis_plugin>
   <pyqgis_plugin name="Dbg_Baumkatastertoolbar" version="2.8.6">
     <description>d.b.g. Baumkatastertoolbar - interaktive Schnittstelle zum d.b.g. Baumkataster</description>
     <homepage>http://www.datenbankgesellschaft.de</homepage>
     <qgis_minimum_version>2.18</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>DbgBaum.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Jan Lippmann, Alexander Barth</author_name>
     <download_url>file:////dc1/dbg/software/produkte/gis/qgis-repo/dbgbaum.zip</download_url>
   </pyqgis_plugin>
   <pyqgis_plugin name="Dbg_Spielkatastertoolbar" version="2.8.5">
     <description>d.b.g. Spielplatzkatastertoolbar - interaktive Schnittstelle zum d.b.g. Spielplatzkataster</description>
     <homepage>http://www.datenbankgesellschaft.de</homepage>
     <qgis_minimum_version>2.18</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>DbgSpiel.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Jan Lippmann, Alexander Barth</author_name>
     <download_url>file:////dc1/dbg/software/produkte/gis/qgis-repo/dbgspiel.zip</download_url>
   </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```