# How do I install a plugin when I have the .zip file for it

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, labeling, installation

I have the zipped file toLabeledLayer-1.0.zip and want to install and use it.  I am using QGIS 2.18.6.  I have unzipped the file and copied it into .qgis2\python\plugins as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline) but it does not appear in the plugin manager.  I have also copied to C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins and 
I have also tried to add the [source](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/toLabeledLayer/) as a repository under settings in the Plugin Manager as suggested in Section 1.3 of [this page](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_plugins/fetching_plugins.html).  Can anyone explain how to install this plugin to me?  Does it not work on this version of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS 2.99. (yes experimental version) has "Install from zip file" under plugins. But your plugin might need updating for 2.99 for it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks very similar to [this recent question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/244095/55203).

I'd recommend installing the plugin using **plugin manager**, if you can.

If that fails, some tips I've found for downloading plugins from zip files extracted into the .qgis2/python/plugins folder

- restart QGIS. New plugins are only found when QGIS starts up
- you will still need to use **Plugin Manager** to install a new plugin added in this way. It will show up in the list of available plugins, but will not be installed (not checked).
- if it's tagged as experimental, you'll need to make sure you allow experimental plugins
- if you make changes to a a repo xml file, under **Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > Settings > Plugin Repositories**, you can use the <kbd>Reload repository</kbd> button to reload that repo file.

If none of those work, it's possible that the minimum/maximum version tags mean that that the plugin won't work for your qgis version.

I don't do this very often, I find this only needs to be done if

- i need to downgrade to an older version of a plugin from [plugins.qgis.org](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) when a newer version is broken
- i need to reinstall one of my own personal plugins which I previously uninstalled

Comment: It does look similar to that questions and neither of them have answers.  It may be a problem with this plugin and the version of QGIS that I am using but I am not sure how to tell if that is the case