# Getting longitude/latitude coordinates from Addresses

Tags: qgis, geocoding, latitude-longitude, address, france

I got a CSV file with more than `15.000` address, and I need to show them on a map of the South-West of France.

I've found the MMQGIS Plugin on QGIS, but it does so without the right SCR.

Do you have any idea to help me convert my addresses? I searched on the Internet and didn't find any adequate solution.

Comment: Could you please a) expand on what you did already and b) give some more details, especially what "SCR" is.

Answer (score 8):

So you want to geocode your file ("translate" adresses to xy coordinates). 
You can search by yourself using this "geocode" keywords and you'll find plenty information.

However, in France, there is a free batch geocoder here : https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/csv

If you use it, you'll obtain a csv with xy coordinates (ESPG:4326) for each of your adresses. 
Then, You can import this file in QGIS using text delimiter filetype :

[image: Import CSV]

You'll find many tutorials on how to import CSV to Qgis like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/importing-coordinate-data-from-excel-into-qgis)

PS: the geocoder is limited to 10 000 rows by batch, so i think you'll have to split your file which is 15 000 rows long.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need some [Geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding). There are several ways that I may refer you to.

1. Using QGIS Plugins, e.g. [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/), [GeoCoding](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/), and others ([check the list](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/geocoding/)) There is even one especially for France, namely [Gban](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/gban/) (not sure if it is directly available in QGIS Plugins menu, perhaps you need to install it manually, related topics: [How do I install a plugin when I have the .zip file for it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244151/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-when-i-have-the-zip-file-for-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [How to install a QGIS plugin when offline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline?noredirect=1&lq=1).
2. There are some geocoding Python libraries, e.g. [GeoPy with the IGN France GeoCoder OpenLS API](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ignfrance) or [Geocoder: Simple, Consistent](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/).
3. Geocoding with the implementation of R and (as was mentioned by @Antoine Watrelot) adresse.data.gouv.fr API based on [BAN data](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/). Article: [Geocoding French addresses with BAN](https://www.frenchkpi.com/geocoding-french-addresses-with-ban/).