# Why Travelling Salesman Problem plugin is not working in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, travelling-salesman

I would like to use the TSP plugin in QGIS. In my current version of QGIS 3.30, it shows an error saying that this plugin was developed for versions 2.14 - 2.99. I tried several versions (e.g., 2.14, 2.16, 2.8.9, etc.) but in each of these, I can't find TSP. Also, there is no option for loading the plugin via a zip file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to stick to ORS Tools plugin, as it supports, amongst other tools and functions, TravellingSalesmanProblem: https://github.com/GIScience/orstools-qgis-plugin

Comment: Thanks. I already use ORS Tools; it's quite good for isochrones. However, TSP in it is cumbersome, as to the best of my knowledge, the input is manually by clicking the points. I believe TSP Plugin accepts the point layer as input, wherein we can select the first/last points.

Comment: I don't exactly remember the names, but -although I agree it is a bit misleading- it is possible to input automatically the points by using the Batch Processing; I'd have to check though exactly the procedure. There's more literature about it on their Community Forum, as in here, for example: https://ask.openrouteservice.org/t/how-to-specify-start-and-end-points-for-directions/2865

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the batch process route; if it works, then it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can install it via zip file for QGIS 2 using the answer from:

[How do I install a plugin when I have the .zip file for it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244151/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-when-i-have-the-zip-file-for-it)

Comment: The plugin uses Google Maps API or OpenRouteService API to obtain distances and geometry of routes and you need to install  the Python library  [ortools](https://pypi.org/project/ortools/) for Python 2.x ( QGIS 2)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.